# Nativescript error when passing response to view

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, nativescript

I am trying to send a `POST` request when an level Of `listview`(In product.xml) is selected and from the response I am trying to build another `listview`(In brand.xml).I have succeeded to send the `POST` request and get the response.But I have failed to pass the response to view.That is I can not build the view.I think the problem is I can't properly send the data(associated with level text),so I failed.I am getting this error:****Attempt to invoke virtual method 'intjave.lang.Integer.intValue()'** on a null object**. null  Here is my code-

product.xml:

```
<Label text="{{ category }}"  horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="center" tap="brand" />
```

product.Js:

```
    exports.brand=function (args) {

    var item =args.object;

     text=item.text;

     getBrand(text);

     };


function getBrand(data) {

    brand.get(data);

        frameModule.topmost().navigate("view/brand/brand");

}
```

**Brand_View_Model:**

```
function BrandViewModel() {

    var viewModel = new Observable({    
    });

    viewModel.get = function (category){
        data = category;

        }

         viewModel.load = function() {

           fetch("http://10.0.2.2:8000/user_signup", {
           method: "POST",
           headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },

           body: JSON.stringify({ 

           category: data,

            })

        }).then(function(response) {
           return response.json();
        }).then(function(data) {

            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

            viewModel.push({
                brand: data[i].brand,

            });

           };  

        });

         }

    viewModel.empty = function() {
    while (viewModel.length) {
        viewModel.pop();
    }
};

    return viewModel;
}

function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}

 module.exports = BrandViewModel;
```

** Brand.js:**

```
var BrandViewModel = require("../../shared/brand_view_model");

var observableModule = require("data/observable");

var page;

var data;

var brandList = new BrandViewModel([]);  


var pageData = new observableModule.fromObject({
    brandList: brandList
});


exports.loaded = function(args) {
    page = args.object;

    page.bindingContext = pageData;

    brandList.empty();
    brandList.load();


};
```

**Brand.xml:**

```
<Page loaded="loaded">
    <GridLayout>
        <ListView items="{{ brandList }}" >
            <ListView.itemTemplate>
                <Label text="{{ brand }}"  horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="center" tap="brand" />
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

Comment: Can you add some more info. The stack-trace + file and line where the error occurred.

Comment: I am new to Nativescript. Where I will find my file stack-trace + file?